# Order against two columns at the same time (intersecting)

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table with the fields **`CommonName`** and **`FirstName`**. Only either field has data, never both. Is there a way to order rows in an intersecting manner on SQL Server?

Example:

```
CommonName FirstName
Bern
           Wade
Ashley
Boris
           Ayana
```

I want records ordered like this:

```
CommonName FirstName
Ashley
           Ayana
Bern
Boris
           Wade
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`CASE` statement](http://www.craigsmullins.com/ssu_0899.htm) to select the value for that row and `ORDER BY` that.

Answer (score 2):

```
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN CommonName is null
    THEN FirstName
    ELSE CommonName
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER BY CommonName + FirstName`, with appropriate `ISNULL(<column>, '')` if they are nullable.

Answer (score 1):

```
order by coalesce(CommonName, FirstName)
```