# MySQL Conditional Ordering

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to sort this way?

Unsorted

```
TIMEIN                TIMEOUT
null                  6/19/2014 12:00:00
6/19/2014 08:30:00    6/19/2014 10:30:00
6/19/2014 13:00:00    null
6/19/2014 19:06:00    6/19/2014 20:36:00
```

Sorted

```
TIMEIN                TIMEOUT
6/19/2014 08:30:00    6/19/2014 10:30:00
null                  6/19/2014 12:00:00
6/19/2014 13:00:00    null
6/19/2014 19:06:00    6/19/2014 20:36:00
```

The list is sorted by TIMEIN descending. If TIMEIN is NULL, TIMEOUT will be the basis in sorting without reordering 'TIMEIN desc'.

Comment: You mean like `BY IFNULL(timein, timeout)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(TIMEIN, TIMEOUT) DESC
```

Comment: Nailed it! I will mark this as an answer after 5min.

Answer (score 2):

There's a handy function called `COALESCE` in MySQL you can just drop into the `ORDER BY` clause.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) is the doc for it
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512767/sql-order-by-two-columns-intermixed-not-priority-based) is an example

And here is what you can append to your SQL:

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(TIMEIN, TIMEOUT) DESC
```

Comment: After posting this answer and looking over @shmsel's answer, I looked up the difference between the two and it seems like `IFNULL` is slightly faster than `COALESCE`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747877/mysql-ifnull-vs-coalesce-which-is-faster